# product ingredients database

Tags: barcode

I'm looking for a database with UPC codes that match up a UPC code to a list of ingredients (if applicable). I've done a lot of searching and come up with some options (including some very expensive ones!) although most of the ones are not up to date and do not contain many recent products.

I'm wondering if there is a database/registry of some sorts somewhere where this information is available in raw format. Any help or ideas that you may have would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What resources did u get ? please share them with us. Only then we can help u .

Comment: Please post resources that you have found